# How to create prompts/notications to the user of an error in Windows Service app?

Tags: service, error-handling, prompt

I am creating a Windows Service app that I would like to have programmatically tell the user that an error has occurred and give hints to the user to correct the error. I was wondering if anyone knows how to do this?
The Windows service app uses an odbc connection and datareader to connect to an MS Access database and an Oracle table, so there are the probable errors that I would be handling with those, I just want to make the user aware of them if/when they occur.

Answer (score 0):

You could write details of the error to an event log or database tables and notify the user via email.

Comment: To write the error to the event log would that just be:
'eventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.ToString())?'

Comment: How would go about notifying the user via email? I have never done that before.